# Вместо переноса строки в docx пробел

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Есть список строк replacements, который принимает такие значения

```
230122  D  80,  S1047962958//64174207980
230122  D  50,  S105495688808//63841124590
```

Для каждого значения replacements выполняется замена в файле

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesWith61.Count; i++)
{ string allReplacements = string.Join("\r\n", replacements.Select(x => $"{x}"));
  ReplaceText(doc, "KeyWord", allReplacements,true);
```

Так выглядит фунция замены

```
 static void ReplaceText(XWPFDocument doc, string findText, string replaceText, bool addIndent) {
    foreach(var para in doc.Paragraphs) {
      foreach(var run in para.Runs) {
        string text = run.GetText(0);
        if (text.Contains(findText)) {
          Console.WriteLine($ "    Найдено текстовое значение '{findText}', заменяем на '{replaceText}'");
          text = text.Replace(findText, replaceText);
          run.SetText(text, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

И сохранение в docx

```
using(var resultStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) 
{
doc.Write(resultStream);
}
```

В конечном файле .docx после каждого значения replacements вместо переноса строки стоит пробел. Пробовал указывать вместо "\r\n" и Environment.NewLine, и "\r", и "\n" результат такой же. В консоли перенос строки есть. В файле нет. Как можно начинать каждое значение с новой строки? (без использования табуляций)

Comment: Есши ворд, то есть ещё знак конца параграфа. То есть закройте параграф, откройте новый. Точно не знаю, как это делается.